# Write a better switch-case function?

Tags: ruby

I am a Ruby newbie.
How can I write better for this function? can i use a hash table instead.

```
def readable_status(status)
  if status == "1" 
    return "go"
  end
  if status == "2"
    return "stop"
  end
  if status == "3"
    return "die"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted to use a hash (as per your question) you could do:

```
def readable_status(status)
   readable = { "1" => "go", "2" => "stop", "3" => "die" }
   readable[status] || "default value"
end
```

Comment: +1. Or `readable.fetch(status, "default_value")`, which might be easier to understand for someone new to Ruby (I prefer your version though).

Comment: @MichaelKohl: `Hash#fetch` is cool. The only difference would be if getting the default value is a costy operation, then `||` would be better because it's lazy.

Comment: @Michael: Would you mind giving the whole solution for the implementation of readable.fetch?

Comment: It's exactly like this post, just replace the line `readable[status] || "default value"` with `readable.fetch(status, "default value")`.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
def readable_status(status)
  %w{go stop die}[status.to_i - 1]
end
```

Comment: i think this is not so good as it make the code harder to read

Answer (score 5):

sure, just use

```
def readable_status(status)
    m = {'1' => 'go', '2' => 'stop', '3' => 'die'}
    m[status]
end
```

you can make it oneliner if you wish:

```
...
{'1' => 'go', '2' => 'stop', '3' => 'die'}[status]
```

Comment: This is nice, though I recommend (to the Ruby newbie OP) to NOT just make a hash constant that is dereferenced when the value is wanted, but instead to leave this logic inside a method wrapper. As @karatedog says, your needs sometimes change; if you keep this in a method you can change the implementation to use more than just a Hash without affecting other areas of your code.

Answer (score 5):

I have failed attempts with Hash-es for this problem because of suboptimal specification which was given me (meaning: business changed specification during development).

Hashes are good until you need to write something a bit more complex than a single value. If you need to change those single values to methods, you have to rewrite everything, as Hashes take the value of the methods by calling them **when** the hash is defined. And if later the method's return value changes, hashes will not be changed.

And it remains readable English :-)

```
def readable_status(status)
  case status 
    when "1" then "go" end
    when "2" then "stop" end
    when "3" then "die" end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the hash is defined inside the method, the hash (and every string in it) is recreated everytime the method is called. Defining a constant prevents this; using a method to acces the values keeps flexibility, as @Phrogz said.

```
READABLE_STATUS_TABLE = {'1'=>'go', '2'=>'stop', '3'=>'die'}

def readable_status(status)
  READABLE_STATUS_TABLE[status]
end
```